# Why are these lines not inside their svg elements?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am fairly new to svg and could use some help figuring out why my lines aren't showing up as expected.  I've used red to indicate where my first line is, and blue where the svg element is - mimics what you see when you mouse over the element in developer tools.  I would expect the line to be somewhere within the svg element.  Instead, it's clearly not and is invisible.  The second line is partially visible but not where I'd like it (in another svg on the next line for "payer duration" similar to the other, nicely centered etc.).

[image: My legend div]

Code:

```css
.durationLegend {
  height:45px;
  width:175px;
  border: #cccccc 1px solid;
  fill: none;
}

.durationLegend p {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.legendKey {
  height: 10px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="durationLegend">
        <p>
            <svg class="legendKey"><line y1="-0.3em" x1="-0.5em" y2="-0.3em" x2="0.75em" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke="Green"></line></svg>
            Duration (secs)
        </p>
        <p>
            <svg class="legendKey"><line y1="0.7em" x1="-0.5em" y2="0.7em" x2="0.75em" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="3px, 3px" stroke="Green"></line></svg>
           Payer Duration (secs)
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `viewbox` defined for your SVG which will determine the co-ordinate space of the SVG

> The viewBox attribute allows to specify that a given set of graphics stretch to fit a particular container element.
>
> The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers min-x, min-y, width and height, separated by whitespace and/or a comma, which specify a rectangle in user space which should be mapped to the bounds of the viewport established by the given element, taking into account attribute preserveAspectRatio.

If you define the elements start / end points outside of the `viewbox space` they be treated as though they were overflowing the SVG but the viewbox will hide that part like `overflow:hidden`.

If you do not define a `viewbox` the element will have the same size as the given width.

**Basically, you have told the SVG 'sub-elements' to start &/or end outside of the SVG "window".**

Useful Article & Tutorials [**http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you use negative x and y values.

```
<div class="durationLegend">
    <p>
        <svg class="legendKey"><line y1="0.3em" x1="0.5em" y2="0.3em" x2="0.75em" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke="Green"></line></svg>
        Duration (secs)
    </p>
    <p>
        <svg class="legendKey"><line y1="0.7em" x1="-0.5em" y2="0.7em" x2="0.75em" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="3px, 3px" stroke="Green"></line></svg>
       Payer Duration (secs)
    </p>
</div>
```

This worked for me.